# DLINK DWM 157 Extra operator report during each operation

Tags: gsm, at-command, gammu

I was working with a D-Link dwm-157 with Firmware Version 1.0.1du, I could send SMS with at commands and everything were ok,
recently I have bought D-Link dwm-157 with Firmware Version 4.0.2MES, because the old module has been stopped production.

There are little changes between calling a commands in these two modules.
In the old one, when I call this:

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*140#"
```

I get this output:

```
OK

+CUSD= 2, "the result of USSD call", 15
```

But in new module the result is :

```
+SPNWNAME: "432", "11", "Mci", "Mci"

+CUSD= 2, "the result of USSD call", 15
```

As you see, in the new module there is an extra report which shows the operator name and network code (`+SPNWNAME: "432", "11", "Mci", "Mci"`), this query slows down the result of my every at command, could you please help me how can I disable that query to speed up my new module.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to make the device work with Gammu (as your question is tagged so), you need to apply following patch to make it work (or wait for newer Gammu release):

https://github.com/gammu/gammu/commit/8f0cd6652b0ccfbedbf1a8efb4c991abd2e0d9fb